# android volley consuming WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, android-volley

i'm trying to learn how Android can interacts with WCF services. so far i can call my function in WCF but i cant parse my parameter from android and get return "System.null.referenceexecption". im using volley to sent my parameter

android

```
   private void registerUser(){
        final String User = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Tvarian = editTextVarian.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Data = editTextData.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Ip = editTextIp.getText().toString().trim();
//      
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    REGISTER_URL, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
//                            msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
//                            hideProgressDialog();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
//                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
                request.put(KEY_USER,User);
                request.put(KEY_TVARIAN,Tvarian);
                request.put(KEY_DATA, Data);
                request.put(KEY_IP, Ip);

                return request;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

and here my wcf function in service1.svc.cs

```
 public string LOGDOWNLOAD(Stream param)
        {
            try

            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(param);
                string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                LogDownload prm = jss.Deserialize<LogDownload>(JSONdata);


                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT_VOLLEY");
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", prm.User));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tvarian", prm.Tvarian));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", prm.Data));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ip", prm.Ip));

                string result = GlobalData.ExecuteNonQuery(command);

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and here IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "LOGDOWNLOAD")]
    string LOGDOWNLOAD(Stream param);
```

i've been trying to use string request and jsonarray request but still get error. 
[image]

Comment: You should declare your parameter as type LogDownload, WCF take care of all serializing job. What type of binding are you using?

Comment: @Oscar i want to use same type like LogDownload what should i do?

Comment: Declare your WCF method as: string LOGDOWNLOAD(LogDownload  logDownload );

Comment: where i have to declare it? in my android or my WCF service, sorry im new in WCF services @Oscar

Answer (score 0):

**C# WCF Code :**

Declaring this method in interface in WCF project :

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "MyServiceMethod",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ResponseModel MyServiceMethod(RequestModel Request);
```

Creating a Request model in C# :

```
public class RequestModel 
{
    public String Param1 { get; set; }
    public int Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a Response Model in C# :

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public String Response { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Android / Java Side Code :**

add gradle for GSON library:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Creating RequestModel in Java:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RequestModel {

    @SerializedName("Param1") // in C# Param1 reference
    public String param1 = "";

    @SerializedName("Param2") // in C# Param2 reference
    public int param2;
}
```

Creating ResponseModel in Java:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("Response") // in C# Response reference
    public String response = "";
}
```

Custom WCF Request using volley json request:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class CustomWCFRequest<T> {

    private Activity mContext;

    public CustomWCFRequest(Activity context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void execute(int method, String url, Class<T> responseType, Object requestObject,
                        Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(requestObject);
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        }
        CustomJsonRequest customRequest = new CustomJsonRequest(method, url, responseType, jsonObject,
                listener, errorListener);
        customRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(customRequest);
    }

    private class CustomJsonRequest extends JsonRequest<T> {

        private Class<T> mType;
        private String mEncodedCharSetProtocol = "utf-8";

        CustomJsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> type, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                          Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                    errorListener);
            this.mType = type;
        }


        @Override
        protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String parsed;
                try {
                    if (mEncodedCharSetProtocol != null) {
                        parsed = new String(response.data, mEncodedCharSetProtocol);
                    } else {
                        parsed = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    parsed = new String(response.data);
                }
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                return Response.success(gson.fromJson(parsed, mType),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

creating WCF webservice calling mechanism in Android / Java :

```
private void callWCFService() {
        String url = "<Your Server URL>";
        url = url + "MyServiceMethod"; // MyServiceMethod is a method name.
        RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel();
        requestModel.param1 = "param1 value";
        requestModel.param2 = 23;
        WebRequest<ResponseModel> req = new WebRequest<>(getActivity());
        req.execute(Request.Method.POST, url, ResponseModel.class, requestModel, new Response.Listener<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ResponseModel response) {
                // Here you got the response of webservice.
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // handle error
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling that method:

```
callWCFService();
```